# How to check if any button in JPanel is clicked by a user

Tags: java, swing

I've been making a bus booking project and I've made a booking page.

The `JPanel` named `PanelSeat` and it contains buttons (about 36 buttons) inside.

I want to check if any button inside `JPanel` is clicked, then disable the button and finally if a user clicks util 3 buttons, it will be stopped or a user can't click it anymore.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
private void CountTicket() {
    try {
        int count = 3;
        Component[] components = PanelSeat.getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            if (components[i] instanceof JButton) {
                if (((JButton) components[i]).isSelected()) { // I wanna check if any button is clicked by a user
                    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Seat Confirmation") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { // confirm message
                        ((JButton) components[i]).setEnabled(false); // disable the button
                        count--;
                        System.out.println("Your ramaining seat : " + count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How do I check if button has been clicked?

Comment: button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("You clicked the button");
            }
        });

Comment: Do I have to use this action into 36 buttons?

Comment: Extend JButton as SeatPanelJButton add static field click count and provide common listener for all (as inner class)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to count how many times a button was pressed, and then disable it with counts involved I would suggest that you wrap the Jbutton class in order to make performing those tasks easier, **this solution is generally better**

```
class JbuttonWrapper extends JButton {
  int count=0;
  public void increment()
  {
     count++;
     if (count==numberOfclicksToDisable)
     {
        this.setEnabled(false);
     }
  }
}

  //then you can simply do the following.
  JbuttonWrapper [] buttons= new JbuttonWrapper [NumbersOfButtonsYouHave];
  for (int i=0; i<=NumbersOfButtonsYouHave;i++)
  {
      buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { buttons[i].increment(); } });
  }
```

**and this solution is based on your code**

```
static int count=3;
    Component[] components = PanelSeat.getComponents();
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        if (components[i] instanceof JButton) {
           { 
               components[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count--;
                }
            });
           }
```

Comment: this code works the same whether you have 36 buttons or 100000 buttons, so don't worry about how you are going to add the actionListener to your buttons.

Comment: and if you want the `count` to be shared by all the instances of the JbuttonWrapper, you can simply make `count`  static

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. but if you don't mind, please can you copy my code and simply to my code because I really have no idea to do that. Maybe if I get code like my code I could understand more

Comment: actually I mean that user must clicks 3 buttons in order to stop it

Comment: @วทัญญูพรมมา no, it will not be suitable neither for him nor you to write down the ready to use code for you. If you cannot understand what stands behind this simple logic than you have to reconsider your Java skills before trying to do something more complicated. SO is a QA site, not `do-this-for-me` site.

Comment: this's the solution that I find thank you so much brother

Comment: @ Phantomazi I'm so sorry

Answer (score 1):

Add [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to `JButton`, check example [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener).

Comment: actually, I can figure out this one but I have 36 buttons and it seems so hard coding to add ActionListener to all buttons inside JPanel, so that's why i want to find a better way.
somehow thank you so much

Comment: Subclass `JButton`, add `ActionListener` to subclassed `JButton` and instantiate button object from instantiated class, not `JButton`.

Comment: can you show me full code please? I can't really imagine on it